# Display portrait iPad App on TV screen that is also in portrait via HDMI

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I am working on an iPad App. I'd like to get my TV, which is rotated to 90 degrees so that it's effectively a 'portrait' display, to display the iPad screen app as shown below. I want the iPad app to be in portrait orientation and display its screen on the TV which is also oriented as a portrait.

[image]

They are connected via HDMI. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: If this is possible it won't be available through your iPad, you should try to rotate the tv's input. But Whatever you do you won't be able to get rid off the black bars completely since iPad's screen is 4:3 ratio while your tv is probably 16:9.

Comment: I am able to get rid of black bars by adding new UIWindow.

Comment: Problem is orientation, my app looks side ways in the portrait TV.

Comment: Ok let me try again. Take your tv's remote in your hand, find video settings and try to rotate the view.

Comment: How are you expecting your TV to understand its in portrait mode ? try setting it as mentioned above

Comment: i don't want my TV to understand orientation, i want my iPad app to work in portrait TV. Its in Side Ways, i am looking for remote i will try the above solution.

Comment: So if i have this code in UIViewController
#pragma mark -  orientation


     -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate 
    {
     return YES;
    }


- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    [self shouldAutorotate];
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}


- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

and after app launch i tap home button two times app goes in background and if i open it, it solved the problem but why do i have to tap home button and make app go in background?